# How does logical shift work in javascript

Tags: javascript, logical-operators, bit-shift

In Javascript, logical shift works differently from other languages.

```
var value = 1543812808507000000
var lowBits = value >>> 0
```

this is javascript code. And the result is 3804366080. But when we developed this logic in java or c, the result was 3804366016.

Which one is correct? How does Logical shifting work in JS?

[image]

Comment: since `1543812808507000000` > `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` it's going to be different

Comment: how can I generate the same result with the js code?

Comment: note: with Chrome only (for now) ... your code is equivalent to `1543812808507000000n & (2n**32n-1n)` - i.e. BigInt

Comment: the result must be 3804366080.

Comment: `how can I generate this result in c or java` - erm ... I thought you did already

Comment: @Ahmet *'the result must be 3804366080'* But if you look at the binary representations you printed yourself, those of C/Java match the lower 32 bit of your large input number. So don't you think the C version is the correct one?

Comment: I do not know which one is correct, but js and java/c work differently. Why? I assumed that js's result was correct. If yes, how can I generate the same result in c or java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [mozilla JS reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER):

> The MAX_SAFE_INTEGER constant has a value of 9007199254740991 (9,007,199,254,740,991 or ~9 quadrillion). The reasoning behind that number is that JavaScript uses double-precision floating-point format numbers as specified in IEEE 754 and can only safely represent numbers between -(2<sup>53</sup> - 1) and 2<sup>53</sup> - 1.

As denoted in the comments already, your input number of 1543812808507000000 is larger than the largest safe integer.

Thus rounding occurs on the JavaScript side.

In contrast, C and Java both use (exact) integral math (below the C version):

```
unsigned long long n = 1543812808507000000ULL;
n &= 0x00000000ffffffffULL;
printf("%llu\n", n);
```

Alternative calculation:

```
n %= 0x0000000100000000ULL;
```

So the C/Java output is the mathematically correct one.

You have great chances to produce the same result in C using floating point math as well:

```
uint64_t n64 = 1543812808507000000ULL;
double d = n64;      // on conversion, rounding occurs!
uint32_t n32 = d;    // back to 32 bit, most significant bits dropped
printf("%lu\n", (unsigned long)n32);
```

For completeness: IEEE754 describes different rounding algorithms, and C standard does not mandate a specific one – actually, it even does not mandate IEEE754 at all. But as both JS and C directly use the same underlying hardware (and all modern hardware follows IEEE754 with same default rounding), this is not of practical relevance...

If you wonder about the cast: `uint32_t` is *likely* to be `typedef`-ed as `unsigned int`, but not necessarily (could be `unsigned long` or even `unsigned short` as well, all legal according to C standard). For `unsigned long`, though, C mandates a range to be covered such that we need *at least* 32 bit, so by casting and using `%lu` format specifier we avoid undefined behaviour due to mismatching format specifier and data type without changing the outcome.

Comment: you're awesome, very clear explanation. I really appreciated!

Comment: OK, seeing now, could have spared all the standard references by using Java examples, as long having 64 bit, int 32 bit and double using IEEE754 is fixed in this language... Solely, I'm closer to C and C++, thus...